# Monotonically increasing functions 123

Tags: functional-equations, monotone-functions

If $f$ is a monotonically increasing function and if $$f\left({x+f(x)\over2}\right)=x$$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, prove that $$f(x)=x$$

Comment: first attempt: f(f((x+f(x))/2)) = f(x), but i dont how and if i could use that

Comment: i also tried this : (x + f(x))/2=y => x= 2y - f(x), again, i dont know what to do after that

Comment: Try to prove f(0)=0

Comment: so we want (x + f(x))/2=0 => f(x)= -x , the result is wrong but i dont understand where i made the mistake

Comment: @fleablood Wrong, monotonically increasing doesn't mean bijective, doesn't mean even injective

Comment: @name replace x by 0. What do you get?

Comment: f((0+f(0))/2)=0 , then i suppose i should find f(something)=0, so that since f is monotonically increasing therefore 1-1 => (0 +f(0))/2 ) = something. how can i find this something?

Comment: I originally mis-read it as $ f(x+f(x)/2)=x . $  Anyone have any thoughts on this one?

Comment: @Robert Israel .Thank you. What i mean is to suggest my mis-read version as a possible new problem. Just looking for opinions about it.I haven't really done anything on it yet.

Comment: $f(x) = (\sqrt{3}-1) x$ satisfies $f(x + f(x)/2) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x)\ne x$ for some $x .$ Let $ (x+f(x))/2 =y.$ CASE 1. $f(x)>x .$ Then $ y>x$  but $ f(y)=x<f(x) $, a contradiction.CASE 2. $f(x)<x. $ Then $y<x$ but $ f(y)=x>f(x) $, a contradiction.

Comment: Why $f(y)=x<f(x)$ in case 1 is a contradiction? Also for case 2

Comment: You haven't use the monotonically increasing condition

Comment: because if f is increasing then y>x implies $f(y)\geq f(x)$ but this is contradicted in case 1.Similarly in case 2.